# Displaying landing page once content-type changed

Tags: php

I have a php page, in which I am setting the content type. Like this:

```
header("Content-type: ".$_GET['ct']);
```

And Content-Disposition like this:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$a['name'].'"');
```

It then forces the download of the file using the readfile() php function.

How can display a HTML page in the background whilst the browser downloads the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply cannot do this via the same .php file.

The best method is to do an iframe or meta type redirect link which redirects to the download page, aka triggers the download while the user is on the html page.

example:

```
<h1>Your Download is Starting Now</h1>
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=/download.php'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to load the pretty download page, but then include a meta redirect to the correct download url.